# Hash sort using the values

Tags: sorting, perl, perl-hash

I have a hash which is shown below. I want list of `keys` in sorted (ascending) order based on their `values`.

If the two different keys have same values, then it should print `keys` which is less first.

Let me show what's going wrong in my example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
          '11' => 1,
          '315' => 4,
          '27' => 3,
          '60' => 4,
          '8' => 3,
          '4' => 2
);

my @keys = sort { $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b} } keys(%hash);
print Dumper(\@keys);
```

Current Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '11',
          '4',
          '27',
          '8',
          '315',
          '60'
        ];
```

I want this to printed like below:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '11',
          '4',
          '8',
          '27',
          '60',
          '315'
        ];
```

Since `60`'s value is `4` and `315`'s value is also `4`. I want `60` to be printed first and `315` later since `60` is lesser than `315` (I mean based on the `key`'s value).
Just assuming this can be done using `Tie::SortHash` (not sure)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the sort to sort numerically on values, then on keys:

```
my @keys = sort { 
    $hash{$a} <=> $hash{$b}
        or
    $a <=> $b
} keys(%hash);
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '11',
          '4',
          8,
          27,
          60,
          315
        ];
```

Refer to `perlfaq4`: [How do I sort a hash (optionally by value instead of key)?](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4#How-do-I-sort-a-hash-(optionally-by-value-instead-of-key)?)

From your command line, you can look up common questions with a command like:

```
perldoc -q sort
```

Answer (score 3):

```perl
use Sort::Key::Multi qw( uukeysort );

my @keys =
   uukeysort { $hash{ $_ }, $_ }
      keys( %hash );
```